# TightVNC Server - remove password

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, vnc

Is it possible, and how would I go about, removing the password from TightVNCServer on Raspbian?

I would like to run it without a password as I only access over LAN, and I am the only user, so I have no need for a password and its a pain in the backside putting it in every time.

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One way is to create a password file and use it (One time
>   configuration).

**Step 1** - **(only if you do not have tightvncserver)** - Install tightvncserver

- sudo apt-get install tightvncserver

**Step 2** - Create a password file using **vncpasswd** command

```
$ vncpasswd
Using password file /home/user/.vnc/passwd
VNC directory /home/user/.vnc does not exist, creating.
Password: [TYPE YOUR VNC PASSWORD HERE]
Verify: [TYPE YOUR VNC PASSWORD HERE]
Would you like to enter a view-only password (y/n)? n
```

**Step 3** - Connect using **vncviewer**, this time using password file -

```
$ vncviewer remotehost.com -p ~/.vnc/passwd
```

**Step 4** - Create an alias so that you do not have to type command all the time -

- Edit ~/.bashrc file

  $sudo nano ~/.bashrc
- Add this line to end of file

  alias connect_pi_vnc="vncviewer remoteaddress:port -passwd ~/.vnc/passwd"
- Reload profile ~/.bashrc

  $source ~/.bashrc

**Step 5** - Now you can connect to your raspberry without password -

```
$connect_pi_vnc
```

And there you go!! You can access pi without typing a password and a long command.

Comment: thanks. will try it later, but looks good.

Comment: Just realised this is for a connection from a linux machine - I am connecting from a Windows machine

Comment: You can use the same tools with windows. You can use this command to create alias on windows : doskey connect_pi_vn="vncviewer remotehost.com -p path_to_passwd_file"

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way of setting a null password, but I suggest you create a public key, and install in your Pi.

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

There are many ways to generate keys, depending on platform.